# HttpClient Pass Multiple objects/variables to[HttpPost] Web API m

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, httpclient

I'm using HttpClient to connect .NET project with my Web API.

I wanted to know how to send multiple parameters to the webapi method in the PostAsJsonAsync() method.

Client Controller:

```
callbackUrl = Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApiAction", new { controller = "Employee", action = "UpdateToleranceRangeByEmployeeId" });
responseMessage = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(callbackUrl, new { companyId = CompanyId, deptId = Depts, divId = Divs, empId = Emps, range = objToleranceRangeModel.ToleranceRange.Value, flag = objToleranceRangeModel.ToleranceFlag });
if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var responseData = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

}
else
{
    logger.Error("Error Inside UpdateToleranceRangeByEmployeeId:" + responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode);


}
```

API Method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
[Route("UpdateToleranceRangeByEmployeeId")]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateToleranceRangeByEmployeeId(int companyId, List<int> deptId, List<int> divId, List<int> empId, double range, bool flag)
{
    logger.Info("Inside UpdateToleranceRangeByEmployeeId");
    HttpResponseMessage response;
    List<EmployeeModel> ObjEmployeeModelList = new List<EmployeeModel>();

    try
    {


        ObjEmployeeModelList = this._iEmployeeServices.UpdateToleranceRangeByEmployeeId(companyId, deptId, divId, empId, range, flag);
        if (ObjEmployeeModelList != null && ObjEmployeeModelList.Count() != 0)
        {
            response = Request.CreateResponse<List<EmployeeModel>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, ObjEmployeeModelList);
        }
        else
        {
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception objEx)
    {
        logger.Error("Error Inside UpdateToleranceRangeByEmployeeId:" + objEx);
        response = Request.CreateResponse<Exception>(HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed, objEx);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I am getting error  :

```
responseMessage = {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RjpcU0FUXFNBVC5BUElcYXBpXEVtcGxveWVlXFVwZGF0ZVRvbGVyYW5jZVJhbmdlQnlFbXBsb3llZUlk?=
  Cache-Contro...
```

Comment: use `[FromBody]` attribute on your parameters to bind the properties of the post body to your parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check whether you have the correct `URL` before making the request.
`404` means that the resource was **not** found.

Comment: Yes i have checked its correct ...i think the parameters i am sending r creating problems